# I want to populate an array in php by the values i recieve by the post method

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, post

```
for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++){
    $try[$i] = $_POST[''echo $i;'.AA1.'];
}
```

But i am getting an error like unexpected echo when i try to use a variable in post methods braces.

Please give me a more optimum solution if you guys find out.

Comment: Put the horse "before" the wagon. `$wagon = $try;` if you want to "echo" that.

Comment: `echo` does output. it has no return value, and you cannot use it to build an array key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++){
    $try[$i] = $_POST[$i.'AA1'];
}
```

Make sure that the following indexes exist in your POST aray: `0AA1` -> `9AA1`.

The error you are getting is caused by several issues:

1. using `echo` inside `[]`. (You don't need to echo a variable's value to use it.)
2. wrong concatenation

Comment: better yet, `preg_grep('/^\dAA1/', $_POST)`, and get only the key:values that were actually passed in